# HTML5 Geolocation issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm writing a program that will determine a user's location after a button is clicked. How I intend for it to operate is that when the window is loaded, the map centers in on the United States but when a "find current location" button is clicked, it zooms it and centers in on the current location of the user. To achieve this I used the HTML5 Geolocation. The program initializes fine and centers in on the united states however when I click on the button it does not center in on my location. The getLocation() function determines my current location coordinates but for some reason does not use these coordinates to reset my mapDiv. The result of this is that the initialize() function is called once again and the page basically reloads with the map centered on the united states rather than my current location. I'm new to JavaScript and JQuery so not really sure what I'm missing. I have included the JavaScript code below. The HTML code just contains a bunch of divs one of which is a map div and also a button that fires the getLocation function when clicked. Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

```
    var mapOptions;
    var map;
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map");
    var latitude;
    var longitude;

    function initialize() {

        mapOptions = {

            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            zoom: 5,

            panControl: false,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                Position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
            },
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
            },
            scaleControl: true,
            scaleControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
            },
            streetViewControl: false,
            overviewMapControl: false
    };


        map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);
    }

    function getLocation() {

        if (navigator.geolocation) {

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);

        }

        else {

            Error("Geolocation is not supported by this browser");

        }



        function success(position) {


                latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                mapOptions.center = pos;
                mapOptions.zoom = 10;

                map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);

        }

        function fail(error) {
            var errors = { 
                    1: 'Permission denied',
                    2: 'Position unavailable',
                    3: 'Request timeout'
            };

            alert("Error: " + errors[error.code]);

        }


    }

    $("#location").click(getLocation);

    $(window).load(initialize);
```

Comment: Normally you would keep a reference to the map and use the setCenter method on it, rather than recreate the map every time the button is clicked.

Comment: The posted code works for me in [jsfiddle (as long as I use https:, if I don't it gives me "permission denied")](https://jsfiddle.net/s714ub7c/1/)

Comment: @geocodezip Yeah just tried the link and it works on jsfiddle but the same code doesn't work on my computer for some reason. That's weird. Does it have to do with my WiFi?

Comment: You probably have denied geolocation for your site (or you don't have https: available).

Comment: @geocodezip I finally fixed it. had to do with the form div. All I had to do was add "return false" at the end of the getLocation() function. I think that is to stop it from submitting the form? Anyway it works now. Thanks.